# How do I use custom javascript through amp-script?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

Not a seasoned programmer but getting a handle on javascript, css, html. I have been successful in creating and loading javascript to use in my standard HTML files. I would like to start using AMPHTML and need to use my own JavaScript for some interaction. Are there some concrete stem-to-stern examples out there? Google AMP's own documentation leaves much to be desired for the uninitiated.

1. I have reviewed the documentation, written my code (passing AMP verification before using amp-script.
2. Supposedly, I have imported my javascript per the  method shown in the documentation. I do not understand what the width and height attributes are there for, or what layout container or fixed has to do with anything.
3. Going by the AMP documents and checking Source in the Development Tools, my file blogHub.js has been accessed and loaded. I see the file there as mentioned and that supposedly means I can use those functions...

So now, I am trying to see some signs of life from my javascript by trying to run functions which spit out console.log messages, but I see nothing. No doubt this is a simple problem for many, but it has me stumped for the moment.

Is sandwiching the relevant code between the  tags a way to corral a separate section away from the rest of the AMP environment or the rest of the DOM?

My desire is to write javascript code which will bring in a .csv file containing information of past blog posts, then update the blog page with this information, then allow the selection of these articles for display in the amp-iframe. It should not be necessary to go into all of that code written or unwritten. I just need to know how to begin using my own javascript from within and AMP document. I am only using Vanilla JavaScript as I am not up to using any of those other libraries at this point. There should not be a need to do so, in any case.

A link to my "sandbox" early version of the page I am working on is found here -- https://michaelsbookcorner.com/HTML-blog/blogFiles/AXX-blogHub.html

Comment: You need to deal with these errors:
The attribute 'onload' may not appear in tag 'section'.
The attribute 'role' in tag 'input' is missing or incorrect, but required by attribute 'on'.
The attribute 'tabindex' in tag 'input' is missing or incorrect, but required by attribute 'on'.
The tag 'img' may only appear as a descendant of tag 'noscript'. Did you mean 'amp-img'?
The tag 'style amp-custom' appears more than once in the document.

Comment: Thank your for getting back to me so soon. There seems to be so little support out there for this and if you know of good sources that would be great! I will comb over your suggestions. I did not know about other pieces required by attribute ON, for example.

Comment: This problem was resolved by other means. I've managed to learn PHP to the point where many of the tasks I had resolved to use JavaScript for are now taken care of.